# Vhost SSL configuration

Tags: apache, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, vhosts

I have installed SSL certificate on my webserver and enabled redirection of all http requests to https using certbot. So far this works when I try to open www.example.com but not with example.com. Just for the record I have changed my domain.com with example.com. I have checked my `access_log` and `error.log` and all of them doesn't show any new entries when I try to open example.com in a browser.

```
curl https://example.com

curl: (60) Issuer certificate is invalid.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

When I execute the same curl command with www.example.com I got to my website. I am using

```
-bash-4.2$ hostname
example
-bash-4.2$ hostname -f
example.com
```

My hostname in `/etc/sysconfig/network` is example. I am also using vhost file:

```
cat /etc/httpd/sites-available/example.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/requests.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and in the httpd.conf I have set to load configuration files from `/etc/httpd/sites-available/*.conf`

The other problem is that when I try to install Cpanel it gives me the following error:

```
2017-03-15 14:10:39  501 ( INFO): Validating that the system hostname ('example') is a FQDN...
2017-03-15 14:10:39  507 (ERROR):
2017-03-15 14:10:39  508 (ERROR): ********************* ERROR *********************
2017-03-15 14:10:39  509 (ERROR):
2017-03-15 14:10:39  510 (ERROR): Your hostname (example) is invalid, and must be
2017-03-15 14:10:39  511 (ERROR): set to a fully qualified domain name before installing cPanel.
2017-03-15 14:10:39  512 (ERROR):
2017-03-15 14:10:39  513 (ERROR): A fully qualified domain name must contain two dots, and consists of two parts: the hostname and the domain name.
2017-03-15 14:10:39  514 (ERROR): You can update your hostname by running `hostname your-hostname.example.com`, then re-running the installer.
2017-03-15 14:10:39  516 (ERROR): ********************* ERROR *********************
2017-03-15 14:10:39  517 (FATAL): Exiting...
Removing /root/installer.lock.
```

Comment: When your created the certificate with certbot, did you specified that it should be for both example.com and www.example.com?

Comment: @gmc yes, I have executed: `sudo certbot --apache -d example.com -d www.example.com`

Comment: Try removing these lines: `RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com`